# How to remove a file with weird characters in the name if find doesn't work?

Tags: linux, filesystems, hfs+

I have a file which has some Unicode characters in its name that are not even shown properly in the console and are not properly processed by the `find` utility. I need to ideally rename, but if that's not possible, at least remove the file in question. I have seen the questions like [How to remove a file where the file name has utf-8 character issues](https://serverfault.com/questions/537749/how-to-remove-a-file-where-the-file-name-has-utf-8-character-issues) and I've tried pretty much all the answers I could find - but they all lead either to `find` with `-delete`, `-exec` or `-print0 | xargs ...` - and neither of these works.

To illustrate what I mean:

```
root@pc:/media/dot_sent/MacHD/Users/<snip>/англ3# ls -li
ls: cannot access 'КОГДА ❓ ??.docx': No such file or directory
total 0
? -????????? ? ? ? ?            ? 'КОГДА ❓ ??.docx'
root@pc:/media/dot_sent/MacHD/Users/<snip>/англ3#
```

So, it can't be accessed by `ls`, `rm` or pretty much anything else, even `find`:

```
root@pc:/media/dot_sent/MacHD/Users/<snip>/англ3# find . -type f -delete
find: cannot delete ‘./КОГДА ❓ ??.docx’: No such file or directory
```

My only success was finding this file's inode:

```
root@pc:/media/dot_sent/MacHD/Users/<snip>/англ3# find . -type f -printf '%i\n'
8215743
```

but even that doesn't help much:

```
root@pc:/media/dot_sent/MacHD/Users/<snip>/англ3# find . -inum 8215743 -exec rm {} \;
rm: cannot remove './КОГДА ❓ ??.docx': No such file or directory
```

A few more bits:

- I am on Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
- The file is on an old MacOS's HFS+ filesystem (on an old Macbook drive physically connected to my Linux box).
- I did ran a correct version of `fsck` on this drive and it found no issues.

Comment: The `? -????????? ? ? ? ? ` is suspicious, it usually means something wrong with the media, MBT/GPT or similar.

Answer (score 0):

@choroba is correct - the  `? -????????? ? ? ? ?`  is a problem - caused by an unsafe or incorrect FUSE umount - you may need to add some additional parameters to your mount command to allow reconnects (or sometimes you need to remove some extra parameters that are causing the problem)